# Correct global action filter registration

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, autofac

How to register global action filter using AutoFac?
The commonly suggested approach (listed below) seems to be not correct because action filter is being resolved once on application start with all the dependency graph initialized. But if action filter uses any disposable objects (like DB session non-directly but via service layer) it works incorrect because the global filter is created once and lives all the time and not being recreated with dependent services disposing.

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    var userLocatorFilter = ContainerHolder.Container.Resolve<UserLocatorAttribute>();
    var userStatusFilter = ContainerHolder.Container.Resolve<UserStatusAttribute>();
    var logErrorFilter = ContainerHolder.Container.Resolve<LogErrorAttribute>();
    // or DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<CustomFilterAttribute>()

    filters.Add(userLocatorFilter);
    filters.Add(userStatusFilter);
    filters.Add(logErrorFilter);
}
```

So I wonder if there is any kind of global filter registration/resolving process that will recreate/dispose it on every request or so? By another words there should be global filter with the limited lifetime.

Let me know if you need more detailed explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use:

`DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));`

... can't you use `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<MyService>()` inside you filters whenever you need them?

Another possible solution might be to pass in the Autofac `Container` as a single c'tor dependency, from which you could then resolve the needed services in a separate `LifetimeScope`.

I'm not sure, but seeing `ContainerHolder.Container` I'm wondering which version of Autofac you're using - have you seen version 3 and the [MVC integration](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MvcIntegration) there?

Comment: `ContainerHolder` is my custom static class for storing Autofac container. Yea, as a result I used solution similar to the one you suggested but wonder if there is a better one.